# how can i setup my web page on radius server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I want to setup wifi hotshot under radius server authentication Something like follows

Internet--------->RADIUS Server-------->Wifi router --- --- --- --- >> Laptop

or

Internet-------->Wifi Router---a) Radius server through LAN ---b) laptop

I searched over internet but found solutions for Windows Operating system I want radius server with Linux OS

A final user/laptop user will use internet like this >

He will search for wifi He will find it with given SSID and will try to connect He will get connected (No use of WEP/WPA/WPA2) RADIUS server screen will appear for Login > Username - Password (If user goes to any website without login, he will get redirected to login page)

After successful login, a user can surf on internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "**captive portal**".

However, usually the portal webpage is hosted *on the firewall*, while your RADIUS server is *separate* and only handles user authentication (i.e. password checking):

```
                                  ┌─ Wi-Fi AP ── client
                                  │             ┌ client
internet ─── router ── firewall ──┼── Wi-Fi AP ─┴─ client
                          │       │            ┌─ client
                          │       └─ Wi-Fi AP ─┼─ client
                          │                    └─ client
                     RADIUS server
                          │
                     user database
```

For small (one-router) networks, the captive-portal system might not need RADIUS *at all*, using just its internal user list.

For example, [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) can act as a router with captive portal support.

(Also note how the above example lists "Wi-Fi" and "router" *separately*. Most "Wi-Fi routers" have only very basic routing/firewalling functions and won't be useful here. And even if you got lucky and bought one with a "web login" option, it will only be useful as long as there's only one of it... Therefore, better have a dedicated router/firewall, and dedicated APs.)